# Highcharts - Pie chart legend remains hoverable on second series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart where I had to build a second series to format the labels for my design brief. In this the data labels on the pie chart show percentages, and the legend shows the labels of the items. Currently my implementation works fine except that the legend is still hoverable, and causes the chart to wash out.

```
        Highcharts.chart({
            chart: {
                styledMode: true,
                renderTo: chart,
                events: {},
            },
            title: {
                text: "",
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                },
                pie: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        distance: 3,
                        padding: 0,
                        // crop: false,
                        // overflow: "allow",
                        alignTo: "toPlotEdges",
                        verticalAlign: "middle",
                    },
                },
            },
            series: [
                {
                    type: "pie",
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    keys: ["name", "y", "selected"],
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    data: highchartsData,
                    innerSize: "25%",
                    showInLegend: false,
                    size: "95%",
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    type: "pie",
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    keys: ["name", "y", "selected"],
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    data: labelData,
                    showInLegend: true,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        });
```

Currently, this is the behavior:

[image: chart hover issue]

Not sure what to do to disable this that I haven't already done.

Comment: Hi @lanierc, You probably don't need to use the second series, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jhmfcty3/ If that doesn't help, please reproduce the issue in jsfiddle.

Comment: That actually solves numerous issues for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the second series, use instead `format` for data labels.

```
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            format: '{point.y}%'
        },
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jhmfcty3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.format